Can't find deleted files/folders from VSCode in Trash on Ubuntu
I'm using Visual Studio Code on Ubuntu 24.04, and when I delete files or folders from within VSCode, they don't appear in the Trash. Instead, they seem to be permanently deleted.
I tried the following troubleshooting steps:

Checked if the files are in ~/.local/share/Trash — they're not.
Verified that my file system supports Trash (using ext4).
Looked into VSCode settings, but it seems the files.enableTrash option is only for Windows.

I have installed VSCode from App center. Is there a way to configure VSCode on Linux so that deleted files go to the Trash instead of being permanently deleted? Or is this the expected behavior?
Edit --
This issues has been observed earlier in the post and as per the answer 0.5.0 release of VS Code has made those changes. However, I am using 1.96.2 and still face similar issue unless I am confusing OS with Ubuntu. My computer has both windows and Ubuntu installed in separate partition and no VSCODE is installed in windows.

Then maybe(*) you are having trouble with this, still open, issue: Deleted files move to another directory, not to trash #174722.  But seriously , no one should depend on the working of Trash.....
